# How to change to package name without changing the package name of Activities in manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio

Let's take an example. I have my activity originally declared in manifest as following.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Then I rename the package. Android Studio just automatically adds the new package name into the activity declaration. Let say the new package name is "com.newname", it will become like the following.

```
<activity android:name="com.newname.MainActivity"/>
```

My question: How can I fully rename the package without automatically adding the new package name into the activity declaration like that?

Comment: you can use the ctrl+ shift + R command.  You can easily find and replace your package name anywhere in your project code easily.

Comment: @L2_Paver That takes extra steps every time I rename the package. What I'm asking for is that if there's any Settings to exclude Activity declaration by default any time I rename package.

Comment: Why are you frequently renaming your packages?